# Python best practice for function that can be called in two different ways

Tags: python, function, arguments

What is the best practice in Python for a function that can be called with two "kinds" of arguments?

As an example, I have a function `run_fit` that can take a `radius` argument and fit at all points in the radius or can take a `region` argument and fit at all points in the custom `region`.

Should `radius` and `region` be Key Word Arguments? Even though exactly one is always required?

Another way of asking my question is: is there a way to capture the fact that neither argument is necessary but at least one must be provided?

Comment: Maybe you could take 2 arguments with one being the argument you're passing in and one a boolean representative of which argument you are passing in?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use keyword args, then use assertions to ensure that the right combination of arguments is passed.

```
def run_fit(radius=None, region=None):
    if not radius and not region:
        raise AssertionError("Supply either radius or region")
    if radius and region:
        raise AssertionError("Only supply one of radius and region")
```

You could also write the assertions directly:

```
assert radius or region, "Supply either radius or region"
assert not (radius and region), "Only supply one of radius or region"
```

but personally I think the first version is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not just for python programming but it can be applied to any programming. If a function is doing two different things like fitting a radius and fitting a region, it is better to split the function into two different functions and give more meaningful name to each like fit_raidus and fit_region instead of one generic name like run_fit.